# iText7 Error while reading cross reference table. table will be rebuilt. file position {0} cross reference entry in this xref subsection

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I have a simple function that is merging together pdfs from an ArrayList using iText7

```
            File pdfMerged = new File("merged.pdf");
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfMerged));
            PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);


            for (InputStream in : files) {
            //Add pages from the each document
                PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(in));
                merger.merge(sourcePdf, 1, sourcePdf.getNumberOfPages());
                
                sourcePdf.close();
            }

            pdf.close();
}
```

While this works most of the time, unfortunately one pdf is giving the following error.

```
2020-08-28 18:05:59,935  ERROR [kernel.pdf.PdfReader] [http-nio-8080-exec-9] Error occurred while reading cross reference table. Cross reference table will be rebuilt.
com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Error at file pointer 1,051,972.
at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.throwError(PdfTokenizer.java:639)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXrefSection(PdfReader.java:839)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXref(PdfReader.java:777)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:532)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1638)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:231)
...
...
...
Caused by: com.itextpdf.io.IOException: file position {0} cross reference entry in this xref subsection.
```

The pdf used in the merge that's causing issues opens just fine in other programs. It is only itext7 that is complaining.

I can't share the problematic pdf, but I can say it's using PDF version 1.6.

This causes the result to be an empty pdf. What does this error mean and how can I fix it or work around it?

Comment: It means that there is an error in the pdf. Different pdf processors tolerate different kinds of errors and repair them differently under the hood. Thus, in case of pdfs which are broken but not too much so, you get different results opening them in different pdf processors. You can fix this by repairing the pdf in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that merger is actually working and merging the files but is throwing the exception anyway. I guess to inform the developer or user it is doing a fix?
If you read the exception carefully it says the "Cross reference table will be rebuilt." So iText is doing some kind of automated fix.

This exception was triggering a different try catch block and the pdf was never being closed as a result.

Strangely I couldn't find any documentation on this in the iText 7 documentation.

At any rate, a simple try catch around the merge function fixed the issue in my case.

```
    for (InputStream in : files) {
    //Add pages from the each document
        PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(in));

        try{
            merger.merge(sourcePdf, 1, sourcePdf.getNumberOfPages());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          //log an error and continue
        }
        sourcePdf.close();
    }
```